# Primefaces Select Many

Tags: primefaces, selectmanycheckbox

Is there any way to use the select many component with an input text inside, in order to be able to both select an option and specify a number of instances of it.
Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/pickList.xhtml

This is what you are looking for~!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Link-only anwers are frown upon, please mention the component or how to configureit and/or give a short code example.